# Using Django_tenants and django_tenant_users for a multi tenancy SAAS

Tags: django, multi-tenant, django-tenants

I am creating a SAAS project, what I want is that I will have clients, and each client can have sub clients/departments. So I came across django_tenants and using it, also django_tenant_users.
But I am little stuck with, how can I manage a multi level tenancy, where each tenant has multiple tenants. Can I do that ?